# How to find same values in arraylist and sort them in sections?

Tags: android, sorting, duplicates

I have an unsorted arraylist with 70000 string values. I want to add same values in separate list.

i.e

if the sample of unsorted list is like this

```
Arraylist[0]->"NewYork"
Arraylist[1]->"DC"
....
....
....
Arraylist[401]->"NewYork"
Arraylist[402]->"Seoul"
Arraylist[403]->"DC"
```

if 2 or more same values are found from the unsorted list, i want to add in separate list or multihashmap which can store same values, as i want to create sections for same values. Result would be like this

Section1:

```
Arraylist1.add("NewYork");

Arraylist1.add("NewYork");
```

Section2:

```
Arraylist2.add("DC");

Arraylist2.add("DC");
```

In my perspective as unsorted list can be random , Creating multiple arraylist is bad approach instead i have used like multihashmap for sections.

The thing is i do not want code because i already implemented it,the thing is above scenario for finding strings and sorting them in each section but my algorithm is way slow, it takes about 30 to 40 seconds, my issue is which is the fastest way to perform this so i can do this in lesser and minimal time.

Comment: Why you have to create all the new ArrayList elements?
I think that a better approach will be to have a HashMap where the keys are the initial strings and the values are Integers where you keep the number of occurrences of the respective string.
You traverse the initial ArrayList once and populate the hashMap updating also the values (number of occurrences).
Then traverse one more the HashMap and eliminate the elements that have just one occurrence.

Comment: i was trying to give an example what i want , yes i have used hashmap but for same files not same string using key as md5 and file path as value but they are unsorted ,so used another multihash to sort them by doing all of this , the time exceeds to more than 30 seconds as it is depened on directories and number of files.

Comment: Now it is a a little bit confusing. make it clear: what data type do you have? what are the keys, what are the values? What do you want to achive?  Also, if you are calculating MD5 sum, it is actually the most time consuming operation, because to calculate it for one file the entire content of the file has to be read.

Comment: Could you maybe count the occurrences like @MarcelPreda suggested, but instead use a `TreeMap`. Then iterate over the `treemap` and build your lists as needed

Comment: Treemap will take more time as i have searched in some links , i am using Guava Multimap (Key,Value) as (md5,filepath) and both are in string.

Comment: To recap: you want to keep only the md5 entries that match multiple files? I did something similar on my own applications that search identical files on Android Play Store. But I've used HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>. Never worked with Multimap, but it should be straight forward: create a new Multimap newMM, foreach key on initial Multimap entries do: Collection<V> c = get(key), if c.size() > 1, and newMM.putAll(key, c) > Hope that it works, untested, just read Multimap interface documentation.

Comment: thanks Marcel,i think hashmap is much better to use instead of multimap as directories /path are always unique , through this i can save identical files.